# Save multiple rating value to django api

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have used reactjs for star rating and has used react-star-rating module for this.I have used django-rest-framework for designing an api.My code is

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)

    #stars
    STAR_CONVERSION = (
            (1, 'one'),
            (2, 'two'),
            (3, 'three'),
            (4, 'four'),
            (5, 'five'),
        )
    tasty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STAR_CONVERSION)
    healthy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STAR_CONVERSION)
    service = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STAR_CONVERSION)

    rating_comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**api.py(/api/ratings/)**

```
class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

class RecipeRatingViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Rating.objects.filter(recipe__id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

frontend(reactjs star rating part)

```
 handleRatingClick(e,data){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(data.rating); # gives value like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        console.log(data.name); gives value like tasty, healthy
        $.ajax({
          url:"/api/ratings/",
          data:data.rating,
          type:'POST',
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr ) {
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
    }

 <div className="row">
  <div className="col s12 m5">
    <div className="card-panel teal">
      <span className="white-text">
          <StarRating name="tasty" caption="tasty" totalStars={5} onRatingClick={this.handleRatingClick.bind(this)} />
          <StarRating name="healthy" caption="healthy" totalStars={5} onRatingClick={this.handleRatingClick.bind(this)} />
          <StarRating name="service" caption="service" totalStars={5} onRatingClick={this.handleRatingClick.bind(this)} />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I get this error

```
**{recipe: ["This field is required."], owner: ["This field is required."],…}
healthy:["This field is required."]
owner:["This field is required."]
recipe:["This field is required."]
service:["This field is required."]
tasty:["This field is required."]**
```

How can i save those rating(tasty, healthy, service) to an api?

Comment: I am not very good at frontend, but it seems that you are not sending the right values, you only have name and rating in our 'data' variable in handleRatingClick function. You should send a json with all the required fields data = {"recipe": int, "owner": int, "tasty": int ..., }.

Comment: That is what i could not send. How can i send recipe and owner value?

Comment: Can you post your serializer as well? I suspect you are not setting the 'owner' and 'recipe', but trying to create them and that's causing the issue.

Comment: Lets understand this usecase. You trying to save rating as soon as a person does a click right? So you will have to write a function which returns the dict as Muj has suggested. You can do so by hardcoding the keys of this dict and make more function to return their values. Am sure a mature rating library will have a easy way to get current rating that is set.